# CSS media query for responsive design not working in SASS

Tags: css, sass, media-queries

Using mobile first design in my CSS SASS file. Height is not changing for different devices after defining media query. Also the card is inside the iframe. it is working fine on tablet but not correctly on mobile and desktop.

```
&.content{
flex-flow: row nowrap;
height:166px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 541px) {
  &.content {
      height: 150px;
    }
}
}
```

HTML tag
`<article class="card content"></article>`

Comment: Show us the entire CSS for the article. You probably have an issue because you're using `&` inside the media query without first selecting the parent element inside the media query.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the rest of the SCSS, you can nest the `media query` in your first rule:

```
&.content {
   flex-flow: row nowrap;
   height:166px;
   
    @media screen and (min-width: 541px) {
       height: 150px;
    }
}
```

As a note, if you are styling an element that appears in an `iframe`, the `iframe` is what determines the `min` and `max` width, and not your main document window. So if your `iframe` is only `300px` wide, that media query condition will not be met.

**Edit:**

To find out how wide the `iframe` is, you can add the following JS to the loaded content:

```
<script>
function alertSize() {
  var myWidth = 0;
  if( typeof( window.innerWidth ) == 'number' ) {
    myWidth = window.innerWidth;
  }
  window.alert( 'Width = ' + myWidth );
}

alertSize();
</script>
```

This will give you an alert to how wide the `iframe` is. From here, you can adjust your media queries based on the width that is returned. This is more of a debugging tool, rather than a solution to automagically select the right media query.

Comment: is there a workaround to get correct dimension for media query in the iframe. Also how do you get iframe dimensions?